# How can I use a localization files and overwrite 1 localization function

Tags: localization, bootstrap-table

I am trying to build a localized bootstrap-table.

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" 
    data-cache="false"
    data-show-footer="false"
    data-show-refresh="false" 
    data-show-toggle="false" 
    data-toggle="table"
     />
```

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    locale :"nl-NL"
});
```

Everything works when I include the locale-file `bootstrap-table-nl-NL.js`

I want to overwrite the footer text showing the pagination text. In the documentation it says I need to define a function for `formatShowingRows`

There seems to be a problem using both `locale` and `formatShowingRows`

```js
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    locale :"nl-NL"
    formatShowingRows: function (pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows) {
        return 'Showing ' + pageFrom + ' to ' + pageTo + ' of ' + totalRows + ' rows';
    }
});
```

When I execute the above script. The pagination text is not replaced with the text I want.
If I remove the locale. It does.

So it looks like `locale` and  `formatShowingRows` are not compatible.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [updateFormatText](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#updateformattext) to change the messages BootstrapTable uses even (or especially) with localization. See https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/wenzhixin/1640 for an example.

Comment: That looks to be working. Is there a way to get some parameters in there ? like pagefrom, pageto and totalrow ?

Comment: Passing parameters is not directly possible. You can either query the values in the function (`this` is a BootstrapTable object and probably contains what you want to know) or set a new callback function when your parameters change.